# Rails uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my development environment, the page loads fine. In production, I get this error:

> NameError (uninitialized constant EventTypesController::EventType):
>     app/controllers/event_types_controller.rb:3:in `index'

Here is my controller:

```
class EventTypesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @event_types = EventType.all
  end

  def update_event_type
    event_type = EventType.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if event_type.update(event_type_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'Event Type Updated'
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end

  def create_event_type
    event_type = EventType.new(event_type_params)
    if event_type.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Event Type Created'
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end

  def destroy_event_type
    event_type = EventType.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if event_type.destroy
      flash[:notice] = 'Event Type Deleted'
      redirect_to :action => :index
    end
  end

  def event_type_params
    params.require('eventtype').permit('description')
  end
end
```

Here is my View:

```
<h1>Event Types</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Event Type Description</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <% @event_types.each do |eventtype| %>
    <% if params[:edit] && params[:edit] == eventtype.id.to_s %>
      <tr>
        <%=form_for :eventtype, :url => {:action => 'update_event_type', :id => eventtype } do |form| -%>
          <td><%= form.text_field :description %></td>
            <td><%= submit_tag("Update") %>
            <%= link_to 'Cancel', {:action => :index} %></td>
        <%end%>
      </tr>
      <%else%>
        <tr>
          <td><%= eventtype.description %></td>
          <td><%=link_to "Edit", {:edit => eventtype.id} %>
            <%=link_to "Delete", {:action => 'destroy_event_type', :id => eventtype.id},:method => :delete ,data: {confirm:'Are you sure you want to delete this event type?'} %></td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
  <%end%>
  <% if !params[:edit] %>
      <%=form_for :eventtype, :url => {:action => 'create_event_type' } do |form| -%>
        <tr>
          <td><%= form.text_field :description %></td>
          <td><%= submit_tag("Add Event Type") %></td>
        </tr>
      <%end%>
  <%end%>
</table>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

This is what happens when I type EventType into production console:

> irb(main):004:0> EventType
>   NameError: uninitialized constant EventType
>           from (irb):4
>           from /home/deploy/track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
>           from /home/deploy/track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`start'
>           from /home/deploy/track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
>           from /home/deploy/track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>           from /home/deploy/track/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`require'
>           from bin/rails

ByeBug Results:

> EventType
>   EventType
>   EventType(id: integer, description: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)
>   (byebug)

Comment: Is your production code up to date? Did you run `rake db:migrate` in production?

Comment: yes i did and i verified the table was created in MySQL. I also manually added records via SQL.

Comment: That's strange then. I would suggest you use a debugger (e.g. byebug) to inspect your index action, and check to see that the `EventType` class is defined. It seems weird to me that it would work locally and not in production if the code and db are up to date.

Comment: What happens when you open production rails console and type EventType?

Comment: @PetrGazarov, I put the results above.

Comment: @mmichael, I added the byebug results above

Comment: What is the complete path where you defined the model?

Comment: wow, I cant believe I missed that. I forgot to add the model file to git so it did not deploy. I apologize guys and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `EventType` table is found in development and not production.

Have you successfully migrated the `EventType` table to production?

```
$ bin/rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: i have ran db:migrate against production multiple times and the table does exist in production